# Criar botão para adicionar texto a lista

Tags: java, android

Estou trabalhando no meu projeto da faculdade e comecei recentemente a programar em Java para Android, utilizo o Android Studio e boa parte da configuração do layout, porem preciso configurar um botão que adicione o que foi digitado em uma caixa de texto a uma `ListView`

Só criei o código base atribuindo os `IDs`

```
package com.bruh.testes;
    
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        TextView textSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSend);
        Button adcionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        Button limpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearList);
        Button sortear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortList);


    }
}
```

Esse é o Layout

[[image: Screenshot mostrando a tela do aplicativo]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txEL2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Então, tens alguma experiência utilizando listas? Array, por exemplo?
O ideal aqui nesse caso seria que você utiliza-se um array de strings, que a cada input da sua caixa de texto receberia uma nova string. E que esse array seria o cara a exibir as informações na ListView, com a a ajuda de um array.

Exemplo:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    TextView textSend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textSend);
    Button adicionar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNew);
    Button limpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearList);
    Button sortear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sortList);
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();

   adicionar.setOnClickListener(
      new View.OnClickListener{
         public void onClick(View view){
         //Adicionar a string do editText no array
         }
      }
   );

    //Passar como ultimo elemento o array que estamos colocando o input do usuário
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
    // Por fim precisamos adicionar o nosso adaptar na list view
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
}
```

Um ponto que tu vai precisar se atentar é o seguinte:

- Estamos adicionando o array no adapter e o adapter na listview dentro do método onCreate. Que é executado uma única vez, quando a tela (activity) é criada, sempre que realizar a inserção de um novo item no seu array será necessário atualizar o adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Para esse exemplo, **NÃO** estou salvando a lista dos Jogadores na memória interna do dispositivo, se for necessário, por favor, me avise e eu irei atualizar a resposta.

Segue então:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listview;
    TextView textSend;
    Button adicionar;
    Button limpar;
    Button sortear;


    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        textSend = findViewById(R.id.textSend);
        adicionar = findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        limpar = findViewById(R.id.clearList);
        sortear =  findViewById(R.id.sortList);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // Inicia a lista dos jogadores.
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); // Inicia o adapter, que, a grosso modo, tem como objetivo preparar a lista de jogadores para ser jogada em um objeto da interface.
        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); // Aplica esse adapter na sua listView.

        configuraBotaoAdicionar(); // Sempre utilize funções separadas para declarar as funcionalidades dos seus componentes.
    }

    private void configuraBotaoAdicionar() {
    adicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nomeJogador = textSend.getText().toString();

            if(!nomeJogador.isEmpty()) {
                arrayList.add(nomeJogador);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                textSend.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Adicionado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nome não pode ser vazio.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Deixei alguns comentários com o objetivo de passar um pouco da didática do uso de Listas, se possível, considere essa resposta como a correta se ela solucionar o seu problema, espero ter ajudado!